# Angular2: write cancellable http get function to retrieve MJPEG images (continuously streaming)

Tags: angular

I am working with a 3rd party backend provider that streams JPEG images over an HTTP connection.

Basically, I do `<img src="{{portal_url}}" />` and it keeps streaming images (from a camera)

The problem, I've realized with this approach is that I have no control over the TCP channel that the browser opens and depending on how the view is cached or not, the TCP channel remains open for a long time even after I exit the view.

Instead, I want to implement a function that uses `http subscribe` to the portal url and renders an image I can display on my browser. The advantage, I believe is I can cancel it anytime, so I don't have to rely on the browser terminating the connection.

Any suggestions on how I go about writing a function?

Note: I can't change the backend - it is what it is.

So far I've got (by looking at other SO answers) but this does not keep streaming images.

```
getBlob(url) {
    this.http.get(url, {
      headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' }),
      responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
    })

      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(blob => {
        var urlCreator = window.URL;
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob));
      })

  }
```

Comment: the response type is stream/row data not json. try after removing `.map(res => res.json())`

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach won't work (my original approach itself) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297249/streaming-mjpeg-images-and-memory-build-up-angular2-http-handling-for-images